# runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000170 overflowed to 0x60200000016c (stl_vector.h)

Tags: arrays

```
class Solution {
public:
    void nextPermutation(vector<int>& nums) {
        
    int ind=-1;
    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    int n=nums.size();
    for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
        if(nums[i]<nums[i+1]){
            ind=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(ind==-1){
        reverse(nums.begin(),nums.end());
       
    }
    for(int i=n-1;i>ind;i--){
        if(nums[i]>nums[ind]){
            swap(nums[i],nums[ind]);
            break;
        }
    }
    reverse(nums.begin()+ind+1,nums.end());
    
}
};
```

i was trying leetcode problem 31 that is next permutation i am getting this error what shoul i do

Comment: What language is this?  What is leetcode problem 31?  What error are you getting?